# What statistical model should I use?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, model

I am trying to create a statistical model for my research. I am dealing with a surgery that has the chance of causing damage to the patient. I have found 5 signs, which I believe are indicators that the surgery will fail. Both the signs and the result of the surgery are binary. I am trying to create a model that will tell me the probability of surgery failing given that 1-5 of the signs are present. I was thinking of using multinomial logistic regression to create my model. Is there better distribution to use to create my model? Any other thoughts?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please consider changing the title of this question to something more descriptive.

Comment: I would agree that a logistic regression model is appropriate. However, this problem lends itself to one of the many machine learning classifiers. These include K-nearest neighbours, decision trees, naive Bayes, SVMs, neural networks etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of building the model? What kind of information do you want to learn from the model? What criteria would help a person choose between the many different kinds of models that estimate probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that the result of surgery has been over-simplified down to a 0/1 outcome, meaning that a much larger sample size will be required in order to build a reliable model, e.g., at least a few hundred surgical failures.  The choice of a model for binary Y is the binary logistic regression model.  Multinomial logistic regression would be used if Y were categorical with more than 2 unordered possible values.  You can use the 5 predictors in the binary logistic model without assuming they are equally important, i.e., without just counting the number present.

To do a credible job will require a large amount of background reading.  I suggest you start by reading Ewout Steyerberg's *Clinical Prediction Models* book as well as introductory papers or books on logistic regression.